# How to change a spritenode opacity

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, opacity, skspritenode

I'm working using XCode 6, Sprite Kit and Swift and I have a node with this declaration:

```
var red = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Rectangle")
```

and I want to change the opacity of the node, but I don't find how, except using a SKAction like FadeIn, FadeOut etc...

I tried changing red.colorBlendFactor but it's only change the opacity of a new color on the node, not the node's opacity...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `SKNode`'s `alpha` property:

```
red.alpha = 0.5  // set red to 50% transparent
```

Comment: is there a way to change it straight from the scene (in User Interface) ?

Comment: how can you change transparency on parts of the images?